# Returning value from a jQuery method

Tags: jquery, methods, return-value

I am calling a method `getSelectedIndex` from a plugin [Megalist](http://triceam.github.io/MegaList/), like this:

```
var selectedIndex = $('#left-list').megalist('getSelectedIndex');
```

However, instead of returning an integer, I get a jQuery object representing the list instead. I tried to call the method directly, both as

```
var selectedIndex = $('#left-list').getSelectedIndex();
```

and

```
var selectedIndex = $('#left-list').megalist().getSelectedIndex();
```

but then I get an error stating there is no method named `getSelectedIndex`. Inserting `.eq(0)` to isolate only the first jQuery object also didn't work. I tried googling for this, but [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821537/why-jquery-plugin-function-is-always-returning-object-instead-of-a-string) [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628159/write-a-jquery-plugin-that-return-values) [pages](http://extraordinarythoughts.com/2011/08/20/understanding-jquery-plugins/) don't seem to provide an answer. The method is defined as follows:

```
getSelectedIndex: function() {
    return parseInt(this.selectedIndex, 10);
},
```

and should return an integer. How can I just call the method to return an integer instead?

**Update:** It seems that doing something like this:

```
window.selectedIndex = -1;
// ...
function listChangeHandler( event ) { 
    // ...
    window.selectedIndex = event.selectedIndex;
    // ...
}

// ...

$('.favorite-link').on('click', function(){
    if (window.selectedIndex != -1)
    {
        if (window.favorites.indexOf(window.selectedIndex) == -1)
        {
            window.favorites.push(window.selectedIndex);
        }
    }
});
```

does the trick, however I would still want to know if this can be done without using global variables.

Answer (score 1):

When the plugin is initialised, no items are selected. Just bind a `change` handler to `#left-list`, you can get the `selectedIndex` from the `event` object:

```
$('#left-list').on('change', function(e) {
  var selectedIndex = e.selectedIndex;
});
```

**[Check the documentation](http://triceam.github.io/MegaList/bin/samples/01%20-%20simple%20inline%20data.html)**

Comment: Ah, but I was doing something like this: `$('.favorite-link').on('click', function(){
  selectedIndex = $('#left-list').megalist('getSelectedIndex');
  if (window.favorites.indexOf(selectedIndex) != -1)
  {
   window.favorites.push(selectedIndex);
  }
 });` Should I resort to using a global variable then?

Comment: I've updated the question with a workaround. I would still like to know if this could be done without using the global variables.

Answer (score 1):

When an item in the megalist has been selected, the class `.megalistSelected` is added to the list item so you could search for a `<li>` with that class using jQuery and get the value of its `list-index` attribute.

With the following megalist markup as an example:

```
   <div class="megalist" id="myList2">
         <ul style="visibility: visible; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
            <li class="megalistItem megalistSelected" list-index="1" style="left: 0px; top: 41px;">Decimal: 1, Hex: 1</li>
         </ul>
   </div>
```

Then...

`$('#myList2').find('.megalistSelected').attr('list-index')`

...will retrieve the index of the item (once an item has been selected of course).

Comment: Yes, that could work, but it still relies on implementation rather than the plugin interface.